# Break a page in iText 7 pdfHTML

Tags: itext, itext7, pdfhtml

I want to break page while converting HTML to PDF using iText 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div style="page-break-after: always">content after this div will flow on the next page</div>
```

Or

```
<div style="page-break-before: always">this div will be started on a new page</div>
```